# javascript onload function works, onresize does not

Tags: javascript, onload

I have a function in my header to adjust the size of an `iframe` and I call it in the footer for both `window.onload` and `window.onresize`.

```
var resize = function(elementId) {
        document.getElementById(elementId).height = parseInt(document.getElementById(elementId).offsetWidth)*0.63;
    };
```

`onload` works:

```
window.onload = resize("youtube");
```

`onresize` does not:

```
window.onresize = resize("youtube")
```

Forgive me if I'm doing anything wrong with my javascript. I'm still kind of new to it.

Comment: Downvoter: what is so wrong about this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are executing the function **right away** instead of returning a function.

So if you log what `window.onload` contains, it would contain `undefined`

You need to return a function (also you *might* want to cache the element, like I did):

```
var resize = function(elementId) {
    return function(){
        var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
        element.height = parseInt(element.offsetWidth) * 0.63;
    };
};
```

What the above does still allows for you to do:

```
window.onload = resize("youtube");
```

Since `resize` now returns a callback `window.onload` (in theory) is now the same as:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var element = document.getElementById("youtube");
    element.height = parseInt(element.offsetWidth) * 0.63;
};
```

Comment: I didn't downvote the answer, I think it's great. But when I implement the change in the header javascript (keeping the footer functions the same), the `onresize` works fine, but `onload` does not.

Comment: @mr.musicman both were not doing anything. Your function was just running immediately. It had nothing to do with the load, your element just so happened to be loaded at the time the function was run twice.

Comment: I never said it wasn't valid. Like I said above, it's a great answer. Both this one and the accepted answer work equally well as far as I can tell.

Comment: And I'm willing to change the accepted answer if I can get help using the function for more than one id.

Comment: @mr.musicman You cannot have multiple `window.onload`s, you can use `addEventListener` or put all of the elements in one function.

Comment: Also if you have a **new** question @mr.musicman Ask a new question. Do not update your old question with a new one. I am rolling back your edit. Sorry.

Comment: @qwertynl You were downvoted because I guess some people do not understand closures well.

Comment: I guess not @ngryman ... I wanted the OP to still be able to use their same code...

Comment: I think just adding a tad bit more explanation might turn some of those votes back up the other way. However (like we discussed in the chat) the downvotes on this are absurd.

Comment: I don't get it. If I ask a follow up as a *new* question then I get hounded for repeating similar material. If I update my question with a follow up, I get hounded for that too.

Comment: @mr.musicman SO is a game, you have to learn how to play it :P Welcome! Enjoy your stay (ohh, and just post the new question then hop into the JS chatroom and we can help you there: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript )

Answer (score 3):

`window.onresize` (and `window.onload` for that matter) should be a function reference;

```
window.onresize = function () {
  resize('youtube')
}
```

Your implementation will execute the functions and assign the return value to the `window` properties.

Comment: So should `window.onload`

Comment: @qwertynl Yes, definitely.

Comment: this works great! Thank you. However, I'm curious why onload was still working when I wasn't calling the function

Comment: @mr.musicman The function ran called right away. The window was probably loaded already and the function ran twice.

Comment: It was calling the function when it got to that line (which was probably when the window loaded anyway).

Comment: if I have multiple iframes, how can I call multiple id's in one function?